# presentModalViewController without animation in storyboard style

Tags: iphone, ios5, segue, xcode-storyboard

I have a existing iPhone application created using traditional nib interface files. Now I am going to convert the application into iOS5 story board style interfaces. I have changed almost all interface files and working fine.

But I am comeup with small issue. My Exsiting application have a code for `presentModalViewController:animated:` without animation. That's by setting `NO` to animated property. I have a problem with doing the same with segues. I can't find any attribute to disable animations in segues.

Comment: I resolve above issue using custom segue. I created custom segue by extending `UIStoryboardSegue` class and added code to presentModalViewController without animating.

Here's the solution to above question.

    #import "ModalViewWithoutAnimation.h"

    @implementation ModalViewWithoutAnimation

    - (void)perform {
        [self.sourceViewController presentModalViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:NO];
    }

@end

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I resolve above issue using custom segue. I created custom segue by extending UIStoryboardSegue class and added code to presentModalViewController without animating. Here's the solution to above question.

```
#import "ModalViewWithoutAnimation.h"

@implementation ModalViewWithoutAnimation 
- (void)perform {
  [self.sourceViewController presentModalViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:NO]; 
} 
@end
```

Thanks